# The ViewModel: MVC 2 vs. MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

In my current MVC2 project I implement my MVC by creating a "model" class that gathers data from the database and runs it through business logic, etc.  Then I have a "Controller" that gets the processed data from the model and sets the values in a "ViewData" class.  This "ViewData" class is a class of getters and setters.  This ViewData is then passed to the view in the Controller like this : `return View(myViewData);`.  Finally, in the View, I bring in the data stored in the ViewData by putting this line at the top of my aspx file.

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Core.UI.Web.ViewData.MyViewData>" %>`

So, is this the way MVC3 is done?  I have a guy on my dev team that is suggesting that the model should be sent, via the Controller, directly to the view like this: `return View(myModel);`.  His reasoning is that this is MVC not M.V.VM.C.

I understand that ViewBag can be used but that just seems like a quick data container.

So, in other words.  ViewData or no ViewData?

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: `ViewBag` is just a quick data container, yes. It can be used to pass model-independent data to a view. With strict design, you'll never need it.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain situations where you might want a view model: to combine data from multiple models/sources, or for specific validation scenarios, etc., but, it's perfectly acceptable to have your view take a model without an intermediary view model, especially if the view model is just a class of getters and setters with no other functionality.

If you're not concerned about exposing methods/properties from your domain model (or if it doesn't apply), I would just pass the model straight to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your instance ViewData is just a model - it is a ViewModel and is perfectly fine, and actually the recommended approach in general to use. The reason being you dont want for instance, a primary key from a customer model rendered in the case of a "create customer" function - as a customer id doesnt yet exist. However for editing a customer record, you surely need a key. So - if you use viewmodels in some cases and not in others, not you are inconsistent in your project.

'yes' you can - but I prefer consistency and using a view model gives you the consistency.

You can also use the model - and thats normally how the MVC demos are setup, but unfortunately like most demos, they don't give you what is architectually best, but what is best in whipping together a 5 minute application.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, although you can get by passing Models to your views, sooner rather than later you'll find yourself wanting to add properties for display purposes only that don't quite belong to the model (e.g. values depending on the current session rather than the model itself.) When you hit that point and it's usually pretty soon you'll be glad you used viewModels.

Technically speaking ASP.NET MVC is not even using MVC but rather Model2. Dino Esposito has [a good article about this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252940.aspx). Furthermore, on his book Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise he even goes as far as saying:

> "It is a sharp and bold statement, but we have to make it: today classic MVC is gone. However, some of its variations are healthy and thrive. They are Model2 for the Web and MVP for both Web and Windows. In turn, and only more recently, MVP has undergone a facelift. In July 2006, Martin Fowler proposed to retire MVP entirely and replace it with two variations Passive View (PV) and Supervising Controller (SVC). “

I wrote a review of this chapter [on my blog](http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/The-Model-View-Controller-is-dead-long-live-the-Model-View-Controller).